# Getting parent node content in xml file by java

Tags: java, xml

In XML file a Parent tag has multiple child tag, with content inside. 
I need the Parent tag info only,

how to get that:

i.e.,

```
 <main>**Name**
      <names>**Harish**</names>
      <names2>**Mathi**</names>
   </main>
```

Here i need only "Name". I no need "Harish","Mathi"...

in this case what i have to include in JAVA code...

Comment: The answer depends which XML parser you are using/want to use.

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\HarishP\\Desktop\\CMS\\TuneTest.xml"));

        //Set up the transformer to write the output string
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);

Comment: try adding the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using XPath:

```
main/text()
```

## UPDATE:

### Example:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("sample.xml");
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("main/text()");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

### OUTPUT:

`**Name**`

Comment: doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(); This one is not working..is there any other alternate solution for this...??

Comment: XPath is one way of querying XML. It's very powerful, but it may be overkill for something so simple.

Comment: can you send a example for this?

Comment: @HarishSaran: you will get the output as you expected.

Comment: <TAG>
<main>**Name**
      <names>**Harish**</names>
      <names2>**Mathi**</names>
   </main>

     <main1>
      <names>**Harish**</names>
      <names2>**Mathi**</names>
    **Names**

   </main1>

    <main2>
      <names>**Harish**</names>
      <names2>**Mathi**</names>
    **Name**
   </main2>
</TAG>



Here i need output as,
**Name**
**Names**

Comment: I need the tag which ever having text content inside it as output.

Comment: In my XML file i'm having many tags which having contents inside it. EX: <main>**Name** <names>**Harish**</names> <names2></names> </main> I need output as : **Name**  <names>**Harish**</names><names2></names> i.e., i no need the root tag in my output but i need it's content.